# mongoose query low performance when using with populate

Tags: performance, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

I need help with this query.
I am querying 8000 documents in AppVisitorwith 4 collections populated.But it is not returning any result. Means it get stuck and after some time nodejs server return 404 error for route in which this query is executed.

```js
 let Keys = yield AppVisitor.find(condition).sort({ createdAt: -1 })
                .populate({ path: 'userDeatils' })
                .populate({ path: 'details' })
                .populate({
                    path: 'skills',
                    match: {
                        $and: [{ value: { $ne: '' } }, { value: { $ne: null } }, { value: { $not: /({R[\d]+})/g } }]
                    }
                })
                .populate({ path: 'courses' });
```

Comment: Hey did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess trying to restructure your collections could help, and use populate function less as its quite a heavy operation.Make sure you know what you are doing when you use populate.